# Change public IP address

Tags: command-line, vpn, ip-address, isp

So I want to know every way to change an external/public ip address. The ways I have found so far are:

- reset router
- go to isp and change it
- vpn

Are there any other ways to change it? (Like command prompt especially). Thank you

Comment: "So I want to know every way to change an external/public ip address." Unfortunately this question is considered to be too broad.  Using a VPN doesn't change your IP. your ip address stays the same, but you are connected to a different network.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your router is assigned an IP address by your Internet Service Provider (ISP) via the [Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHCP), you may be able to force a change in the external IP address assigned to it by your ISP by resetting the router or powering it off and on. That may or may not result in a new IP address being assigned to your router depending on how your ISP allocates IP addresses. With some ISPs, the ISP's DHCP server may assign the same IP address to your router as was used before. E.g, an ISP might assign the same IP address again, if the [media access control (MAC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_access_control) address of your router is unchanged, which would normally be the case unless you've replaced the router. For other ISPs, simply powering off or resetting the router can give you a new external IP address for the router.

You could purchase, or use a free, [Virtual Private Network (VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network)) service which will assign your system an IP address from whatever IP address range the VPN service provider uses for its VPN clients. Some VPN service providers have servers in multiple countries, so that you can select the country with which the IP address you get is associated.

Alternatively, you could use a [proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) service. You could then [configure applications, such as a web browser, to route their traffic through the proxy server](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/proxy/settings/), so that systems on the Internet will see the IP address of the proxy server for connections from your system, rather than the IP address assigned to your router by your ISP. As with VPN service providers, some proxy server services have systems in multiple countries, so you can use an IP address that's assigned to a system in another country.

You could also buy [Secure Shell Server (SSH)](http://.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) service, just as you could purchase VPN or proxy server service, establish an SSH connection to the SSH server and [tunnel network traffic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol#Secure_Shell_tunneling), e.g., web browser traffic, through the SSH connection. E.g., if you are using a Microsoft Windows system, you could [use the free PuTTY program to establish a SOCKS proxy](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/proxy/putty/) that you could use for a proxy server. Systems on the Internet, e.g., websites, would then see the IP address of the SSH server when you connect to them, rather than the IP address assigned to your router by your ISP.

You could also use [Tor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29) software, which is free and anonymizes your traffic, so external systems don't see your ISP-assigned IP address. Instead, your traffic passes through multiple servers, disguising your IP address from the end system and also the intermediary systems on the Tor network.

All but the first method, which assumes you are getting a new external IP address for your router, rely on you routing connections through some external server. E.g., [you can change proxy server settings from the command prompt](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/proxy/settings/), but you are going to need access to some external proxy server for that to result in external systems seeing a different IP address for connections from systems behind your router.

Answer (score 0):

If your home connection have an static IP, you can't change it by rebooting the router. The only way would be asking your ISP which may not comply. If your home connection have a dynamic IP (like mine), rebooting the router may work. You can do that by manually turning it off and then on or logging in into the admin dashboard and rebooting from there.

Using a VPN (or Tor, or other services) doesn't "change" your IP, but adds another layer in your connection. So you are connected to the VPN server and then the VPN connects to the website or service that you want to use. However this may slow down the speed of the service that you are using, so you should use something that is near to you. Free services may cap your speed connection to the VPN, so its best to use a paid one if possible. The route of your ISP to the VPN service may also affect the quality of the connection which is something that you cannot fix.

Please note that a VPN service may (or may not) log what you do when using their service.

Some free/trial services. I'm listing these services as examples, use them at your own risk and discretion:

- Tunnelbear (http://tunnelbear.com)
- Tor (only works on websites that you open in the Tor browser, https://torproject.org)
- SurfEasy (bundled in Opera browser)
- Proton VPN (http://protonvpn.com)

Tor is not recommended is some use cases, so it is recommended to read their About page.

You can test if it works using https://wtfismyip.com or searching "my ip address" in https://duckduckgo.com.